What does the notation "$\text{coeff}(\lambda) in | \text{some_matrix} |$" means?
I was self-studying the formulas to find out the mean curvature of an iso-surface ($f: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$):
$$
K_M = \frac{ \nabla f \ . \ \mathbf H(f) \ . \ \nabla f^T - \| \nabla f \|^2 \ Trace(\mathbf H(f)) }{ 2.\| \nabla f \|^3 }
$$
$$
K_M = \frac{ - \text{coeff}(\lambda) \text{in} \left | \begin{matrix}
\mathbf H(f) - \lambda I & \nabla f^T \\
\nabla f & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right | }{ 2.\| \nabla f \|^3 }
$$
But I don't understand what "coeff( lambda) in |some_matrix|" notation means. Most likely |some_matrix| designates the determinant, but aside from that I don't know what "$\text{coeff}(\lambda) \text{in}$" means, I don't know what operation it represents.
These comes from:
Curvature formulas for implicit curves and surfaces by Ronald N. Goldman

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Page 643 : Now since ∇F and Ps × Pt are both parallel to the surface normal, there is a constant λ such that Ps × Pt = λ∇F.

And the formula follows from Th.4.3,. expanding the RHS of the corresponding curvature formula: can you verify it?

But yes, Gaussian curvature uses the determinant.
